# add class for opacity when scrolling but remove when back at the top

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got a sticky header that disappears when scrolling down and reappears while scrolling back up. 
This is the code

```js
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('#main-header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
    if (scroll >= 500) {
        $("#main-header").addClass("nav-shadow");
    } else {
        $("#main-header").removeClass("nav-shadow");
    }
});

setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);

function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If scrolled down and past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('#main-header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
          $('#main-header').removeClass('nav-shadow');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#main-header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
              $('#main-header').addClass('nav-shadow');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
#main-header {
  height:120px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background: red;
  z-index: 50000;
}
body {
  color: $grey-color;
  padding-top: 120px;
  }
.nav-up {
  top: -120px !important;
}
.nav-shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#page-content {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-down" id="main-header">
  <p>header</p>
</div>
<div id="page-content"></div>
```

I've also added a class for a box shadow on scroll. However, I need to remove the box shadow class once the header is back at the very top of the page. Anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: if scrollTop is 0 then it is at the top. removeClass to remove the class. It looks like `scroll` is undefined inside your scroll event listener.

Comment: why do you fire hasScrolled in a setInterval, instead of inside the scroll event ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `if (scroll >= 500)` to `if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 500)`. And you don't need to set interval just call your function onscroll

```js
// Hide Header on on scroll down
var didScroll;
var lastScrollTop = 0;
var delta = 5;
var navbarHeight = $('#main-header').outerHeight();

$(window).scroll(function(event){
    didScroll = true;
    if ($(window).scrollTop() >= 500) {
        $("#main-header").addClass("nav-shadow");
    } else {
        $("#main-header").removeClass("nav-shadow");
    }
     hasScrolled();
});
/*
setInterval(function() {
    if (didScroll) {
        hasScrolled();
        didScroll = false;
    }
}, 250);
*/
function hasScrolled() {
    var st = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Make scroll more than delta
    if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta)
        return;

    // If scrolled down and past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
    if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
        // Scroll Down
        $('#main-header').removeClass('nav-down').addClass('nav-up');
          $('#main-header').removeClass('nav-shadow');
    } else {
        // Scroll Up
        if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
            $('#main-header').removeClass('nav-up').addClass('nav-down');
              $('#main-header').addClass('nav-shadow');
        }
    }

    lastScrollTop = st;
}
```

```css
#main-header {
  height:120px;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out;
  background: red;
  z-index: 50000;
}
body {
  color: $grey-color;
  padding-top: 120px;
  }
.nav-up {
  top: -120px !important;
}
.nav-shadow {
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
}
#page-content {
  height: 200vh;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="nav-down" id="main-header">
  <p>header</p>
</div>
<div id="page-content"></div>
```